# Manually access a route with react router and a spring boot backend

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a react UI that opens a new tab to another UI's sub route.

Example: a button in `localhost/app1` opens a new tab to `localhost/app2/usersettings` - This works in a development scenario but once I roll out the applications as package, it fails. The issue is, that it just redirects me back to `localhost/apps2`

Here's my setup

```
@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/","index.html");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/usersettings","index.html?path=usersettings");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/{x:[\\w\\-]+}","index.html");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/**/{y:[\\w\\-]+}", "index.html");
    }
```

```
const MainPage = () => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
                <Route path="index.html" element={<Navigate to="/"/>}/>
                <Route path="/usersettings" element={<UserSettings/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </Box>
    );
};
```

Navigating to `/usersettings` in app2 works perfectly if I click the route, but once I manually enter the url or redirect by a button from app1 it just loads the home route.

How am I supposed to setup the routes so router receives the correct path variable?

I am totally lost.

Thanks

Comment: I think it because when you manually entering the URL or redirecting from app1 to app2, browser is likely performing a full page refresh, which is causing the issue, so you need to ensure that your server is configured to serve the correct `index.html` file for each sub-route! Let me know if you want me to explain it to you with examples.

Comment: Correct, the server/hosting service should be configured to return/serve the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. How are you running this app?

Comment: @Freeman yeah that would be nice if you had the time for it!

Comment: @DrewReese I have one project with front and backend in one. The backend is just a spring boot service. When shipping the software I usually run it as a package and that's when it won't redirect to sub routes.

Answer (score 2):

Alrighty, first of all you need to configure your server to serve the correct `index.html` file for all routes that should be handled by your React application, as I told. for that purpose, you maybe should do this by setting up a catch-all route that serves the `index.html` file for any unrecognized routes.

let me explain it for you with an example :

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "index.html");
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/**", "index.html");
}
```

it should allow your React application to handle all routes correctly, including routes that are opened in a new tab or redirected from `app1`.

and in your React application,you can then set up your routes like this:

```
const MainPage = () => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>}/>
                <Route path="/usersettings" element={<UserSettings/>}/>
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/"/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </Box>
    );
};
```

as you see,configuration sets up a catch-all route that redirects to the home page for any unrecognized routes and it ensures that all routes are handled correctly by your React application

good luck bro !

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking your time to help me. I seem to be getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with this approach though.

Comment: Here's a screenshot from the Network tab https://imgur.com/a/rqXgxBk

Comment: sure, we will fix them together, don't worry bro !

Comment: Man, regardless of the outcome, this is super wholesome. Thanks haha